# adjustViewBounds analogue in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to make an image take up container width and have height based on image ratio. In XML, I would use `adjustViewBounds` on `ImageView`. Is there an analogue in Compose? If not, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Update for Compose 1.0+

`SimpleImage` is deprecated and replaced by `Image` which is bit more customisable - at least it allows to set modifiers. The general idea of maintaining image ratio stays the same:

```kotlin
val painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.android_studio_logo)
val imageRatio = painter.intrinsicSize.width / painter.intrinsicSize.height
Image(
    painter = painter,
    contentDescription = null,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .aspectRatio(imageRatio)
)
```

## Old answer for 0.1.0-dev06

I don't think that something like `adjustViewBounds` is currently supported out of the box in 0.1.0-dev06.

By looking at the source code, `SimpleImage` doesn't seem to be customizable. All it does is drawing the image over the `Box` with exact same size as the image:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SimpleImage(
    image: Image,
    tint: Color? = null
) {
    with(DensityAmbient.current) {
        val imageModifier = ImagePainter(image).toModifier(
            scaleFit = ScaleFit.FillMaxDimension,
            colorFilter = tint?.let { ColorFilter(it, BlendMode.srcIn) }
        )
        Box(LayoutSize(image.width.toDp(), image.height.toDp()) + ClipModifier + imageModifier)
    }
}
```

But based on that implementation, effect like `adjustViewBounds` can be achieved by using different size modifier. Instead of specific exact size we can apply `LayoutWidth.Fill` to occupy entire width and then adjust height using `LayoutAspectRatio` with the ratio of the image:

```kotlin
val image = imageResource(R.drawable.android_studio_logo)
val imageRatio = image.width.toFloat() / image.height.toFloat()
val imageModifier = ImagePainter(image).toModifier(scaleFit = ScaleFit.FillMaxDimension)
Box(LayoutWidth.Fill + LayoutAspectRatio(imageRatio) + imageModifier)
```

Of course for better reusability and readability we can wrap it in a function.
Here is how the result looks like:

[image: preview comparison]

Comment: Staring with beta01 imageResource is now an extension function on Image Bitmap. So...
bitmap = ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = R.drawable.android_studio_logo)

Comment: Can anybody suggest what would be the equivalent way of specifying the modifier based on the latest version of compose. The constructs LayoutWidth and LayoutAspectRatio have been deprecated and removed in the latest version of compose, https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation

Comment: but adjustViewBounds would consider available height for image, this solution doesn't do it, bottom content won't be visible if there is no scroll, image will take the whole space

Answer (score 0):

At the time of version 1.0.0-alpha06, it's similar to the accepted answer.

For example, for vector resources, the code is as follows.

```
@Composable
fun VectorImage(asset: VectorAsset) {
    val imageRatio = asset.defaultWidth.value / asset.defaultHeight.value
    Image(
        asset = asset,
        contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
        modifier = Modifier.aspectRatio(imageRatio).fillMaxWidth()
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this without needing to calculate the image ratio

```
Image(
    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.test),
    contentDescription = "test",
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth
)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.